# Extracting and converting string to float

Tags: php, floating-point

```
function extractNumber($str) {
  $re = '/((?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/';
  preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
  return isset($matches[1]) ? floatval(trim($matches[1][0])) : 0;
}

echo extractNumber('4,158.60'); // 4
```

https://eval.in/816428

Whats the most reliable way to convert string to float? Also, I don't want to necessarily return float when there're no decimals, how would I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with `parseFloat()` ?

Comment: @TahaPaksu is a javascript function, not PHP

Comment: Ok, my bad. `floatval()`?

Comment: @TahaPaksu Because it won't remove the commas.

Comment: @TahaPaksu If you see the description, thats what I tried and it strips the number.

Comment: `floatval(str_replace(",","",$str));` ?

Comment: Or [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)?

Comment: @ficuscr `number_format` does the opposite.

Comment: number_format works the reverse way. It converts number to desired string.

Comment: Is the string compatible with the current locale?

Comment: `number_format($val, 0, '.', '');` Just saying, about as much sense as a str_replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to get the current locale's thousand seperator:

```
$locale_def = localeconv();
$thousands_separator = $locale_def["thousands_sep"];
```

But, if the string is not compatible with the current locale, and we have a hardcoded thousands separator:

```
$thousands_separator = ",";
```

Then we need to replace them:

```
$str = str_replace($thousands_separator, "", $str);
```

Then at last, we can use `floatval`:

```
$float = floatval($str);
```

(Optional) If the string has no decimal part, we can use it as an integer:

```
$num = fmod($float,1) === 0 ? intval($float) : $float;
```

Comment: Re `fmod`, what if the decimal is `99.00`? It would return an int?

Comment: Fmod will return 0 and it will return 99

Comment: Exactly, so basically if a number is a valid float with a decimal thats 0, it would convert it into an int, which is not ideal. :(

Comment: What do you want the output to be when the decimal is 0 then? In your question you say *I don't want to necessarily return float when there're no decimals*